# How to set a filed number to a prop when user leave the page without submitting the form in Omnitrue?

Tags: forms, adobe-analytics

I'm new to Omniture implementation. I'm having a task right now which I'm kinda of lost.

In a form page, I need to be able to set a unique number for each filed in the form, and when a user close the page without filling in all the filed. I need to know the number of the last filed that has information and populated this value into a prop. Is it possible to do? if so, can anyone be kind and explain it for me?

Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "filed" ? You talk about form fields ?
If I've understood your need, you wish to follow the submitting rate for a form and also save the related values of each field ?

So you need, to create and eVar to populate the form name.

To follow the conversion rate :

This eVar needs to be present on the form page and on the submitting confirmation page.
2 events : one for the form page and an another for the submitting confirmation page.

To catch the value of filled forms :

1 prop for each field, populated on the submitting confirmation page.

Following the technical context and the traffic volume, you're gonna to apply specific javascript solution.

Hoping it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your Adobe Analytics implementation consultant about the plugin Form Analysis.
It should do what you want.

It will automatically intercept any visitor that exit a page qith a form wothout click the submit button, and will send to adobe the last input he interacted with.

Claudio.